# Cancellation token in Parallel.ForEach loop not working

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, cancellation, .net-4.7.2, parallel-foreach

I can't seem to stop the `Parallel.ForEach` tasks below on CTRL-C, am I not catching the exceptions correctly? I have a long running operation in a while loop.

Can anyone tell me what I'm not doing correctly here?

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    StartAllReaders(cts.token)
    Console.CancelKeyPress += (s,e) => {
       cts.cancel();
       e.cancel = true;
    }
}

public static void StartAllReaders(CancellationToken cts)
{
            try
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(
                _readers, 
                new ParallelOptions{MaxDegreeOfParallelism=10,CancellationToken = cts},
                (reader, state) =>
                {
                    reader.Start();
                    while (!cts.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        cts.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                        try
                        {
                            reader.ReadTelemetry();
                            Thread.Sleep(reader.TimeDelay);
                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            //log something
                            continue;
                        }
                    }}); 
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException e)
            {
                Logger.Info("Readers are stopping.");
            }
}
```

Comment: The `Console.CancelKeyPress` code wont run util the StartAllReaders is finished. Also your code does not compile as it is.

Comment: Also having a while loop like that inside the foreach seems wrong. Do you have 10 readers and you want to run them in parallel?

Comment: CancellationToken is working. `Parallel.ForEach` is misused though and doesn't allow the application to *inspect* the token, because it's frozen by those `Thread.Sleep(reader.TimeDelay);` calls

Comment: What does `ReadTelemetry` do and why is `Thread.Sleep` called? It matters. `Parallel.ForEach` is the wrong tool for the job, but knowing what the actual job is will help find the right tool. `Parallel.ForEach` is a tool for *data parallelism*, ie processing a lot of in-memory data by using all available cores to process chunks of that data. It's explicitly *not* meant for IO or async operations. It will even use the calling thread to process data, which makes the application appear frozen. Calling `Thread.Sleep()` inside `Parallel.ForEach` will just freeze the CPU itself

Comment: ReadTelemetry is reading and processing data from log files, I need a delay between reading the files in a while loop.

Comment: It is doing the job fine now, abelt not best practices, only problem is I can't trigger the cancellation token

Comment: It's not doing the job at all. It's wasting 10 threads doing nothing and prevents cancellation *explicitly*. To perform asynchronous operations like this you need asynchronous calls. Magnus' answer shows how simple it is to do this with the *correct* tools

Comment: How many readers are there? 10? Or is 10 an attempt to throttle reading from 1000 readers? It matters. Magnus' answer will start 100 tasks for 100 readers

Comment: Previous approach similar to Magnus' answer resulted in high CPU utilitsation and parallel foreach improved that. Approx 40 readers.

Comment: That was a problem with the previous code then. Parallel.ForEach is still the wrong tool. If you had a problem with too many tasks, you probably need throttling. Unless you have 40 cores, starting 40 readers at once with the same delay will result in waves of 40 reads every N second.

Comment: Post the previous code and explain what you actually want to do - poll 40 readers, 10 at a time, every N seconds.

Comment: What .NET platform are you targeting? .NET 7?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos exactly as per Magnus' answer - he got exactly what I needed to do, but the CPU utilization is just too high (~60%)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias .Net Framework 4.7.2

Comment: What does `ReadTelemetry()` do? Does it make any blocking calls? Thread rescheduling is expensive so .NET will use spinwaiting before evicting a blocked thread from a core.

Comment: It's reading log file by chunks, then passing them to the next pub/sub for regex parsing

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing a little bit here but I believe something like this is what you are after. It will run all the readers in parallel (with a startup delay) and cancel them when cancellation is signaled.

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(5000); //Cancel after 5 sec.
    var ct = cts.Token;
    var _readers = new List<Reader> { new(), new() };
    try
    {
        await Task.WhenAll(_readers.Select((r, i) => StartReader(r, i, ct)));
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException e) when (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("stop");
    }
    
}

public static async Task StartReader(Reader reader, int index, CancellationToken ct)
{
    await Task.Delay(index * 1000, ct); //Optional startup delay to avoid all readers starting at the same time. 
    while (true)
    {
        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        reader.ReadTelemetry();
        await Task.Delay(reader.TimeDelay, ct); //Will throw on cancellation
    }
}

public class Reader
{
    public int TimeDelay { get; set; } = 100000;
    internal void ReadTelemetry()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `while(true)` it should be `while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no I would rather put a ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); before the ReadTelemetry to be consistent and always catch cancellation.

Comment: @Magnus, appreciate your response - exactly the logic I implemented previously, except the 40 readers were crashing my system

Comment: Just makr sure they dont read at the same time. By using a startup delay.